# OpenCL kernel causes application to run indefinitely and only stops after I shut down my IDE

Tags: c, opencl

I am trying to run portions of [this](https://github.com/claf/MJPEG/tree/master/tima_seq_version/src) code on the GPU using OpenCL. I am now trying to run the function which deals with YCbCr to RGB conversion.

*Please note that as of now I am not trying to optimize the GPU code. I simply want an output identical to that on the CPU.*

The function is originally written like this:

```
void YCbCr_to_ARGB(uint8_t *YCbCr_MCU[3], uint32_t *RGB_MCU, uint32_t nb_MCU_H, uint32_t nb_MCU_V)
{

    uint8_t *MCU_Y, *MCU_Cb, *MCU_Cr;
    int R, G, B;
    uint32_t ARGB;
    uint8_t index, i, j;

    MCU_Y = YCbCr_MCU[0];
    MCU_Cb = YCbCr_MCU[1];
    MCU_Cr = YCbCr_MCU[2];
    for (i = 0; i < 8 * nb_MCU_V; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 8 * nb_MCU_H; j++) {
            index = i * (8 * nb_MCU_H)  + j;
            R = (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 1.402f + MCU_Y[index];
            B = (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 1.7772f + MCU_Y[index];
            G = MCU_Y[index] - (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 0.34414f -
                (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 0.71414f;
            /* Saturate */
            if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            ARGB = ((R & 0xFF) << 16) | ((G & 0xFF) << 8) | (B & 0xFF);
            // ARGB = 0xFF << 8;
            RGB_MCU[(i * (8 * nb_MCU_H) + j)] = ARGB;
        }
    }
}
```

The variables of this function are declared in `main.c` in the following way:

```
cl_uchar* YCbCr_MCU[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL};
cl_uint* RGB_MCU = NULL;
```

Memory for these variables is being allocated in this way:

```
if (screen_init_needed == 1) 
{
                    screen_init_needed = 0;

.....
.....
//Some code

for (index = 0 ; index < SOF_section.n ; index++) {
YCbCr_MCU[index] = malloc(MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v);

YCbCr_MCU_ds[index] = malloc(MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v);

}

RGB_MCU = malloc (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v * sizeof(cl_int));
}

break;
}
```

I directly copied and pasted it in my `.cl` file and made a few minor changes to make it agree with OpenCL standards. My modified OpenCL code looked like this:

```
__kernel void YCbCr_to_ARGB(__global uchar* YCbCr_MCU[3], __global uint* RGB_MCU, uint nb_MCU_H, uint nb_MCU_V)
    {        
        __global uchar *MCU_Y, *MCU_Cb, *MCU_Cr;
        int R, G, B;
        uint ARGB;
        uchar index, i, j;

        MCU_Y = YCbCr_MCU[0];
        MCU_Cb = YCbCr_MCU[1];
        MCU_Cr = YCbCr_MCU[2];

//Same code as the first code snippet
        ......
        ......
        ......

    }
```

When I built and ran my application with the above kernel code in my `.cl` file, I got errors. One of the errors stated that OpenCL doesn't allow pointer to pointer arguments.

In order to get around these errors, I modified my code again to look like this:

```
__kernel void YCbCr_to_ARGB(__global uchar YCbCr_MCU[3], __global uint* RGB_MCU, uint nb_MCU_H, uint nb_MCU_V)
{         
            __global uchar *MCU_Y, *MCU_Cb, *MCU_Cr;
            int R, G, B;
            uint ARGB;
            uchar index, i, j;

            MCU_Y = &YCbCr_MCU[0];
            MCU_Cb = &YCbCr_MCU[1];
            MCU_Cr = &YCbCr_MCU[2];

    //Same code as the first code snippet
            ......
            ......
            ......   
}
```

When I built and ran the application again, I did not get any errors. This prompted me to write the host code for this kernel.

It looks like this:

```
 color_kernel= clCreateKernel(program, "YCbCr_to_ARGB", &ret);

//YCbCr_MCU for YCbCrtoARGB
cl_mem colorMCU_GPU= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 3 * sizeof(cl_uchar), NULL, &ret);


//rgb_MCU for YCbCrtoARGB
cl_mem RGB_GPU= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,  sizeof(cl_uint), NULL, &ret);
```

I called the kernel arguments exactly where the original function was called in `main.c`. I performed the remaining steps for this kernel in the following way:

```
if(color&&(SOF_section.n>1)
{
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, colorMCU_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0, 3 * sizeof(cl_uchar), YCbCr_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, RGB_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0,  sizeof(cl_uint), RGB_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&colorMCU_GPU);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&RGB_GPU);
ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&max_ss_h);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&max_ss_v);

ret = clEnqueueTask(command_queue, color_kernel, 0, NULL, NULL);

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, RGB_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), RGB_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);

//YCbCr_to_ARGB(YCbCr_MCU, RGB_MCU, max_ss_h, max_ss_v);
```

After I run and build the code with these arguments, the code keeps running indefinitely (The output of this is supposed to be a movie clip running on a screen. With this code, I only get a black screen). I have to close Eclipse and reopen it to make additional changes to the code after this.

**What is causing the program to behave like this? Is there anyway to safely run this function on the GPU?**

Update:

I followed Anders Cedronius' advice and changed my kernel code in the following way:

```
__kernel void YCbCr_to_ARGB(__global uchar YCbCr_MCU[3], __global uint* RGB_MCU, uint nb_MCU_H, uint nb_MCU_V)
{
   printf("Doing color conversion\n");  

    __global uchar *MCU_Y, *MCU_Cb, *MCU_Cr;
    int R, G, B;
    uint ARGB;
    uchar index, i, j;

    i= get_global_id(0);
    j= get_global_id(1);

    MCU_Y = &YCbCr_MCU[0];
    MCU_Cb = &YCbCr_MCU[1];
    MCU_Cr = &YCbCr_MCU[2];

    if (i < 8 * nb_MCU_V && j < 8 * nb_MCU_H)
    {
            index = i * (8 * nb_MCU_H)  + j;
            R = (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 1.402f + MCU_Y[index];
            B = (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 1.7772f + MCU_Y[index];
            G = MCU_Y[index] - (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 0.34414f -
                (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 0.71414f;


            /* Saturate */
            if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            ARGB = ((R & 0xFF) << 16) | ((G & 0xFF) << 8) | (B & 0xFF);
            // ARGB = 0xFF << 8;
        RGB_MCU[(i * (8 * nb_MCU_H) + j)] = ARGB;


}

printf("Finished color conversion\n");
}
```

My host code for calling the kernel now looks like this:

```
color_kernel= clCreateKernel(program, "YCbCr_to_ARGB", &ret);
```

I am setting the work size and the kernel arguments in the following way:

```
ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, colorMCU_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0, 3*sizeof(cl_uchar), YCbCr_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);
chk(ret, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer");

ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, RGB_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0,  sizeof(cl_uint), RGB_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);
chk(ret, "clEnqueueWriteBuffer");


ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&colorMCU_GPU);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&RGB_GPU);
ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&max_ss_h);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *)&max_ss_v);


size_t itemColor[2] = {1, 1};

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 2, NULL, itemColor, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
chk(ret, "clEnqueueNDRange");

ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, RGB_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_uint), RGB_MCU, 0, NULL, NULL);


clFinish(command_queue);
```

I ran this code and I NO LONGER get a black screen. However, the kernel for "YCbCr to RGB" is not being recognized now. **Even my printf comments are not being displayed on the output console. It is like my code does not have the color conversion function.**

Update:

I hadn't changed the name of my kernel in the command `EnqueueNDRangeKernel`. I changed the name and now the printf statements are appearing on the console. However, I am not still not getting the correct output.

```
size_t itemColor[2] = {1, 1};

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, color_kernel, 2, NULL, itemColor, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

chk(ret, "clEnqueueNDRange");

clFinish(command_queue);
```

Update:

I followed pmdj's advice and made changes to my kernel code. It now looks like this:

```
__kernel void YCbCr_to_ARGB(__global uchar* Y_GPU, __global uchar* Cb_GPU, __global uchar* Cr_GPU, __global uint* RGB_MCU, uint nb_MCU_H, uint nb_MCU_V)
{  
    __global uchar *MCU_Y, *MCU_Cb, *MCU_Cr;
    int R, G, B;
    uint ARGB;
    uchar index, i, j;

unsigned char   iid= get_global_id(0);
unsigned char   jid= get_global_id(1);

    // MCU_Y = &YCbCr_MCU[0];
      // MCU_Cb = &YCbCr_MCU[1];
      // MCU_Cr = &YCbCr_MCU[2];

      MCU_Y= Y_GPU;
      MCU_Cb= Cb_GPU;
      MCU_Cr= Cr_GPU;

    if (iid <= (8 * nb_MCU_V) && jid <= (8 * nb_MCU_H))
    {

            index = iid * (8 * nb_MCU_H)  + jid;
            R = (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 1.402f + MCU_Y[index];
            B = (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 1.7772f + MCU_Y[index];
            G = MCU_Y[index] - (MCU_Cb[index] - 128) * 0.34414f -
                (MCU_Cr[index] - 128) * 0.71414f;


            /* Saturate */
            if (R > 255)
                R = 255;
            if (R < 0)
                R = 0;
            if (G > 255)
                G = 255;
            if (G < 0)
                G = 0;
            if (B > 255)
                B = 255;
            if (B < 0)
                B = 0;
            ARGB = ((R & 0xFF) << 16) | ((G & 0xFF) << 8) | (B & 0xFF);

        RGB_MCU[(iid * (8 * nb_MCU_H) + jid)] = ARGB;

        }
}
```

In the host code, I created and allocated memory for 4 new variables:

```
Y_ForGPU= (cl_uchar *)malloc(MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v);

Cb_ForGPU= (cl_uchar *)malloc(MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v);

Cr_ForGPU= (cl_uchar *)malloc(MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v);

//Now will do it for RGB
RGB_testing= (cl_uint *)malloc (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v * sizeof(cl_int));
```

I created buffers in the following way:

```
cl_mem for_Y= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v), Y_ForGPU, &ret);


cl_mem for_Cb= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v), Cb_ForGPU , &ret);

cl_mem for_Cr= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE| CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v), Cr_ForGPU, &ret);

//rgb_MCU for YCbCrtoARGB
cl_mem RGB_GPU= clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v * sizeof(cl_int)), NULL, &ret);
```

I then set the kernel arguments, executed the kernel and sent the computed data back on the host:

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &for_Y);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &for_Cb);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &for_Cr);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_mem), &RGB_GPU);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 4, sizeof(cl_uint), &max_ss_h);
ret |= clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 5, sizeof(cl_uint), &max_ss_v);


const size_t itemColor[2] = {100, 100};

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, color_kernel, 2, NULL, itemColor, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
clFinish(command_queue);

//Copy result to the host
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, RGB_GPU, CL_TRUE, 0, (MCU_sx * MCU_sy * max_ss_h * max_ss_v * sizeof(cl_int)), RGB_testing, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

However, now my code simply terminates abruptly. Why might this be happening?

Update:

My code is now working. The problems were probably occurring due to differences in the pointers. I set the Y, Cb, Cr and RGB variables (which I created) equal to the original variables in the host code.

```
//---Setting color variables equal to array elements----//

Y_ForGPU= YCbCr_MCU[0];
Cb_ForGPU= YCbCr_MCU[1];
Cr_ForGPU= YCbCr_MCU[2];

//----RGB is being assigned value-----//

RGB_testing= RGB_MCU;
```

Comment: You should not have the inner loop in the kernel program. The kernel program should just do the math YUV->RGB for a single 'element' then you use clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to segment the workers to the GPU's.

Comment: @AndersCedronius I have updated my code to include your suggestion. However, my kernel is not being recognized now. I have included the details in my question above.

Comment: Don't go just guessing things. If you want to do something meaningful grab a book and start reading, you won't get anywhere otherwise.

Comment: @Jovasa I have referred to quite a few sources to reach my current level of understanding of OpenCL. I asked this question because I am struggling to apply my knowledge to this particular function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only cause for your problems (there may be more I haven't yet spotted), but you have a type mismatch in your `YCbCr_MCU` kernel argument. You can't have pointer-to-pointer arguments, this is true. Simply removing the `*` won't fix it though.

In particular, the line

```
MCU_Cb = &YCbCr_MCU[1];
```

in the kernel gets 1 byte past the start of whatever YCbCr_MCU points to, which, looking at the host code, is actually the start of the array of pointers, not the array of pixels.

```
ret = clSetKernelArg(color_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&colorMCU_GPU);
```

It looks like `YCbCr_MCU` is supposed to be an array of 3 pointers to the Y, Cb, Cr planes containing your source pixels. You will need to pass these to your kernel as 3 direct pointers to the 3 arrays instead of a pointer to the 3 pointers. In other words, turn it into Y, Cb, and, Cr arguments, and set them to `colorMCU_GPU[0]` through `colorMCU_GPU[2]` on the host.

Comment: I made changes in my code according to the advice you have given me. My program abruptly terminates when I run it. Why could this be happening? Could this be a result of faulty memory allocation?